# How can I return JavaScript from a string with preg_match_all in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I would like to read everything JavaScript out of a string with `preg_match_all`.

```
$pattern = '~<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>~su';
$success = preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

array(0 => '<script>alert("Hallo Welt 1");</script>');
```

The result now contains the script tag as well.
I would like to exclude this tag.

My Sample [Online Regex](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/rk4#tab-preg-match-all) with Sample Code.

Comment: Classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Most likely regex is not your tool.

Comment: Add a real capture group `(…)` around the inner part, and use result set `[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Regex* is the wrong tool for parsing XML/HTML. You should use a DOM parser instead. *XPath expressions* is a language specialized on parsing DOM structures.

```
$html = <<<_EOS_
<script>alert("Hallo Welt 1");</script>
<div>Hallo Welt</div>
<script type ="text/javascript">alert("Hallo Welt 2");</script>
<div>Hallo Welt 2</div>
<script type ="text/javascript">
              alert("Hallo Welt 2");
</script>
_EOS_;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("<!DOCTYPE html><html>$html</html>");
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$scripts = $xpath->query('//script/text()');

foreach ($scripts as $script)
  var_dump($script->data);
```

Comment: Thanks for this practicable solution… i think it's the best way...